# Roots and spacing: symmetrical brackets

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, brackets, root

I have this simple MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \lim_{n\to \infty} \bigl(\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1}\bigr)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
   \lim_{n\to \infty} \bigl(\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3-1}\,\bigr)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> I have observed, now, that I do not get symmetrical round (or square, or curly) brackets. *Why aren't symmetrical brackets automatically generated with the same space? Is the reason due to the presence of roots?*

Comment: I have developed the habit of adding `\,` when a radical is followed by a parenthesis. There is no “asymmetry”: just an unfortunate symbol clash. There are other cases where inserting `\,` is good to fix a clash. In other cases `\!` should be used to “fill a hole”.

Comment: @egreg I thank you for your cordiality. I was preparing a class assignment for my students and noticed this asymmetry. I gather from your comment that it is not my lack of knowledge of some LaTeX specific tricks :-)

Comment: @egreg Any additional responses are always appreciated. Otherwise, if I do not receive any answer, I am always available at any time to close the question :-).

Comment: you are comparing the space from the tip of ( to the 3 and the end of the overbar to the ) but to tex all characters are rectangular boxes compare the horizontal space from the  tip of ( to the leftmost part of √ and you will see it is much closer to the space before ) so the `\,`  is similar to italic correction a visual adjustment to account for the shape of the characters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your clear explanation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by the comments.